# Cursor location and pixel value in a Jupyter notebook inline image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Python 2.7.x with a Jupyter Notebook, matplotlib and %pylab backend with the inline flag 
`%pylab inline`
to print images below active cells.  I would like to be able to move my cursor over an image and know it's location and pixel value An example could be: 
(x,y,val) = (123,285,230)
but I am not particular about any of the specifics of this example.

Comment: I think you should ask a new question. In the question as it was originally, you wanted to know how to get coordinates/values on mouseover in Jupyter Notebook. This is a valid question and you received one answer to it (it might not be the only valid one). It would then be totally your choice whether or not to accept the answer; if you are happy with using the notebook backend, you may accept it, but if you think that a solution with JavaScript on the png images would still be better, leave it unaccepted, but clearly state in the question that you are looking for such a solution.

Comment: The other totally unrelated problem is about getting the notebook backend to work. This has nothing to do with coordinates and requires a totally different problem description. It therefore makes sense to move that part to a new question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `%matplotlib inline` backend displays the plot outputs as png images. It may be possible to write some JavaScript for the Jupyter notebook to obtain the color and pixel on mouse over an image in the cell output.

However it may be much easier to just use the `%matplotlib notebook` backend, which keeps the matplotlib figure alive when plotting it to the output and therefore the usual built-in mouseover functionality is readily available.

[image]

Note the picker in the lower right corner of the image, which displays `x`,`y` and the value of the current pixel.

Comment: How can I turn it off so that in my next code cells, I do not have interactive plots. I just want to use it for 1 cell.

Comment: re enable the inline mode for the next cells: `%matplotlib inline`

Answer (score 11):

To expand on ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer, you can use [`mpl_connect`](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) to provide a callback on your clicks and [`ipywidgets`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to show an output of your callback. If needed, you can break up the code in different cells.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as wdg  # Using the ipython notebook widgets

# Create a random image
a = np.random.poisson(size=(12,15))
fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(a)

# Create and display textarea widget
txt = wdg.Textarea(
    value='',
    placeholder='',
    description='event:',
    disabled=False
)
display(txt)

# Define a callback function that will update the textarea
def onclick(event):
    txt.value = str(event)  # Dynamically update the text box above

# Create an hard reference to the callback not to be cleared by the garbage collector
ka = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```