# Printing cursor coordinates in a matplotib figure in a Jupyter notebook: the smooth way

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I want to display the coordinates of my cursor in an image displayed with matplotlib within a Jupyter notebook.

I am using the `%matplotlib notebook` magic as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43396282).

While this provides a nice answer for a static figure, this results in a huge amount of flickering and bugs (the figure sometimes not showing) when used in an interactive setting where the figure is constantly redrawn during slicing. For example,

```
%matplotlib notebook
from ipywidgets import interact
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

vol = np.random.uniform(size=(16, 16, 16))

@interact(z=(0, 15))
def show(z):
    plt.imshow(vol[z])
    plt.show()
```

Without `%matplotlib notebook`, the figure is updating without any flicker, but does not show the cursor coordinates. With the magic, the coordinates are displayed, but the flickering is unbearable.

Is there a way to have pixel coordinates without flickering in that simple situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the use of `plt.show()`, which will replace the figure. Instead you probably want to *update*  the existing figure.

```
%matplotlib notebook
from ipywidgets import interact
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

vol = np.random.uniform(size=(16, 16, 16))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(vol[0])

@interact(z=(0, 15))
def show(z):
    im.set_array(vol[z])
    im.set_clim(vol[z].min(), vol[z].max())
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Note the the above provides the same functionality as the code in the question, i.e. each array is normalized individually. However, you might decide to set the color normalization only once such that all arrays share the same color limits.

```
%matplotlib notebook
from ipywidgets import interact
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

vol = np.random.uniform(size=(16, 16, 16))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(vol[0], vmin=vol.min(), vmax=vol.max())
fig.colorbar(im)

@interact(z=(0, 15))
def show(z):
    im.set_array(vol[z])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```